# AudioTrack: start called from a thread

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I using AudioTrack in static mode to reproduce the same signal over and over again.

I have followed the example in here and sometimes it works perfectly, but sometimes it throws this error and it produces no sound:

```
AudioTrack: start called from a thread
01-23 15:26:16.902: W/libutils.threads(1133): Thread (this=0x3973b8): don't call waitForExit() from this Thread object's thread. It's a guaranteed deadlock!
```

This is the source code. I'm trying to ensure that I call stop and reload the data for the next "play" execution.

```
     public class SoundPlayer {
     // originally from http://marblemice.blogspot.com/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html
        private int numSamples;
        private double sample[];
        private byte generatedSnd[];
        private AudioTrack audioTrack;

        public SoundPlayer(float duration, int sampleRate, double freqOfTone) {
            super();
            this.numSamples = (int) (duration * sampleRate);
            this.sample = new double[numSamples];
            this.generatedSnd = new byte[2 * numSamples];
            // fill out the array
            for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
                sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));
            }
            // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
            // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
            int idx = 0;
            for (final double dVal : sample) {
                // scale to maximum amplitude
                final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
                // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
                generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
                generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

            }
            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
            audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        }

        public void playSound() {
            if ( audioTrack.getPlayState() ==  (AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING | AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED )) {
                audioTrack.stop();
                audioTrack.reloadStaticData();
            }
            Log.i("Audio", "playState: " + audioTrack.getPlayState());
            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.reloadStaticData();
        }

}
```

If we open the android source code, it does not explains a lot:

```
void AudioTrack::start()
{
sp<AudioTrackThread> t = mAudioTrackThread;

LOGV("start");
if (t != 0) {
    if (t->exitPending()) {
        if (t->requestExitAndWait() == WOULD_BLOCK) {
            LOGE("AudioTrack::start called from thread");
            return;
        }
    }
    t->mLock.lock();
 }
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem once.

Simply put, if you happen to have stuff running in more than one thread you have to make sure that creating the `AudioTrack` and calling `play()` and `stop()` on it **must** happen in the same thread.

However, it doesn't mean that you have to create the audio samples in that thread, too. In case you use static audio data (`AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC`) you can preload or generate them elsewhere and then use it even multiple times throughout the lifetime of your app.